# Openni error: cannot connect to Kinect device

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-fuerte, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed Fuerte RGBDSLAM on Ubuntu 12.04, and I am having issues running openni.launch with my Kinect Xbox 360.
When I input the command "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch," the following errors appear:

```
...
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [24264]
[ERROR] [1371132230.942545630]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1371132230.949755309]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1371132230.957609969]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1371132233.084870097]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

I believe it was already answered that both the "Exception AttributeError" and the "[ERROR]...Tried to advertise..." messages are harmless, but I'm still having problems with the [INFO] error:

```
[ INFO] [1371132233.084870097]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

Any advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65029/openni-error:-cannot-connect-to-kinect-device/) by [rosslam](https://answers.ros.org/users/5111/rosslam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-13**:
The info error is missing from your question.

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2013-06-13**:
please try with "lsusb". I should see something similar Bus 002 Device 019: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor. Bear in mind that Ubuntu 12.04 has some problems with USB3.0, so plug the Kinect into a USB2.0 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with my device. Don't worry about the errors. It's normal. I followed this answer:
http://answers.ros.org/question/51286/openni-doesnt-find-kinect/

If you have problems uninstalling some openni packages try to reinstall their dependencies and again uninstall them one-by-one

---

Originally posted by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) with karma: 141 on 2013-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1